# Solidity, create contract from contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Based on [documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/contracts.html#creating-contracts) it should be possible to create new contract from contract

```
contractAddress = new OwnedToken(name);
```

When I invoke this method from contract, the [address](http://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0x3b1412ee52e56c9ffbd79e01a0568bbbf7529399) I receive seems to be normal address and not contract.

Is this even possible (I remember I read somewhere that only normal accounts can send contract creating transactions)?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> Is this even possible (I remember I read somewhere that only normal
>   accounts can send contract creating transactions)?

This is definitely possible.

> When I invoke this method from contract, the address I receive seems
>   to be normal address and not contract.

I'm not sure which address you are talking about.
This kind of design works well:

```
contract Factory {
    address[] newContracts;

    function createContract (bytes32 name) {
        address newContract = new Contract(name);
        newContracts.push(newContract);
    } 
}

contract Contract {
    bytes32 public Name;

    function Contract (bytes32 name) {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

In the array newContracts, you will have the addresses of the Contracts created by the factory.

Then if you want to call the Name from the first Contract created in the Factory contract, you should use :

```
con.Name();
```

after having defined

```
Contract con = Contract(newContracts[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried and it works flawlessly. I had bug somewhere else in my contract. It seems etherscan.io does detect this kind of contract address correctly (if this is really a think). Is there any difference between contract created by contract or if it is created manually?

Comment: @Ales No, difference between a contract that's created manually or by another contract.  Some explorers don't show as much internals and you might see more at https://live.ether.camp

Comment: @Hcharlanes, very useful example! Thanks! What's going to be the value of **msg.sender** in the Contract constructor? The address of the account that sent the transaction or the address where contract Factory is deployed?

Comment: Won't this just return a Contract named after the address?

Comment: Do you need to do new Contract() instaed of Contract()?

Comment: If you want to access the contract object directly after creation take the createContract function line `address newContract = new Contract(name);` and replace `address` with `Contract` for inline instantiation.

Answer (score 7):

I don't have enough rep to comment on Hcharlanes's answer but since I wasted an hour on it and lots of other people are using his sample, the line

```
Names[i] = con.Name();
```

is a bug. You can't assign off the end of a dynamic array. This has to be

```
Names.push(con.Name());
```

to not crash, but of course that code doesn't make any sense for any real purpose. You'd want to push the name onto that array immediately when creating the contract. Otherwise the sample is great! Hope this helps!